# How to send message with headers to ActiveMQ Artemis queue via JMX protocol?

Tags: java, jmx, activemq-artemis

I want to send a message to an ActiveMQ Artemis queue, but I don't understand how to pass headers there such as: message lifetime, message type and other headers, not properties

Here is the code for using the method to send a message to the queue via the JMX protocol:

```
 public static void sendMessage(QueueControl queueControl, JMXMessage jmxMessage, String user, String password) throws Exception {
        boolean flag = false;
        queueControl.sendMessage(jmxMessage.getJmxProperties(), Integer.parseInt(jmxMessage.getJmxHeaders().getJmxType()),jmxMessage.getJmxBody(),flag,user, password);
    }
```

Class JMXMessage:

```
public class JMXMessage implements Serializable {
    private JMXHeaders jmxHeaders;
    private Map<String, String> jmxProperties;
    private String jmxBody;

    public JMXMessage(JMXHeaders jmxHeaders,String jmxBody) {
        this.jmxHeaders = jmxHeaders;
        this.jmxBody = jmxBody;
    }

    public JMXHeaders getJmxHeaders() {
        return jmxHeaders;
    }

    public void setJmxHeaders(JMXHeaders jmxHeaders) {
        this.jmxHeaders = jmxHeaders;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getJmxProperties() {
        return jmxProperties;
    }

    public void setJmxProperties(Map<String, String> jmxProperties) {
        this.jmxProperties = jmxProperties;
    }

    public String getJmxBody() {
        return jmxBody;
    }

    public void setJmxBody(String jmxBody) {
        this.jmxBody = jmxBody;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Headers" + "\n" + "{" + "\n" +
                "   MessageId=" + jmxHeaders.getJmxMessageId() + ";" + "\n" +
                "   Priority=" + jmxHeaders.getJmxPriority() + ";" + "\n" +
                "   Timestamp=" + jmxHeaders.getJmxTimestamp() + ";" + "\n" +
                "   Expires=" + jmxHeaders.getJmxExpires() + ";" + "\n" +
                "   Type=" + jmxHeaders.getJmxType() + ";" + "\n" +
                "   DeliveryMode=" + jmxHeaders.getJmxDeliveryMode() + ";" + "\n" +
                "   CorrelationId=" + jmxHeaders.getJmxCorrelationId() + ";" + "\n" +
                "   ReplyTo=" + jmxHeaders.getJmxReplyTo() + ";" + "\n" + "}" + "\n" + "\n" +
                "Properties" + "\n" + "{" + "\n" +
                "   Properties=" + jmxProperties + ";" + "\n" + "}" + "\n" + "\n" +
                "Body" + "\n" + "{" + "\n" +
                    jmxBody + ";" + "\n" + "}" + "\n" + "\n";
    }
}
```

Class JMXHeaders:

```
public class JMXHeaders implements Serializable {
    private String jmxType;
    private String jmxExpires;
    private String jmxDeliveryMode;
    private String jmxReplyTo;
    private String jmxMessageId;
    private String jmxTimestamp;
    private String jmxCorrelationId;
    private String jmxPriority;

    public JMXHeaders(String jmxType, String jmxExpires, String jmxDeliveryMode, String jmxReplyTo, String jmxMessageId, String jmxTimestamp, String jmxCorrelationId, String jmxPriority) {
        this.jmxType = jmxType;
        this.jmxExpires = jmxExpires;
        this.jmxDeliveryMode = jmxDeliveryMode;
        this.jmxReplyTo = jmxReplyTo;
        this.jmxMessageId = jmxMessageId;
        this.jmxTimestamp = jmxTimestamp;
        this.jmxCorrelationId = jmxCorrelationId;
        this.jmxPriority = jmxPriority;
    }

    public JMXHeaders(String jmxType, String jmxExpires, String jmxDeliveryMode, String jmxReplyTo) {
        this.jmxType = jmxType;
        this.jmxExpires = jmxExpires;
        this.jmxDeliveryMode = jmxDeliveryMode;
        this.jmxReplyTo = jmxReplyTo;
    }

    public String getJmxExpires() {
        return jmxExpires;
    }

    public void setJmxExpires(String jmxExpires) {
        this.jmxExpires = jmxExpires;
    }

    public String getJmxMessageId() {
        return jmxMessageId;
    }

    public void setJmxMessageId(String jmxMessageId) {
        this.jmxMessageId = jmxMessageId;
    }

    public String getJmxTimestamp() {
        return jmxTimestamp;
    }

    public void setJmxTimestamp(String jmxTimestamp) {
        this.jmxTimestamp = jmxTimestamp;
    }

    public String getJmxCorrelationId() {
        return jmxCorrelationId;
    }

    public void setJmxCorrelationId(String jmxCorrelationID) {
        this.jmxCorrelationId = jmxCorrelationID;
    }

    public String getJmxPriority() {
        return jmxPriority;
    }

    public void setJmxPriority(String jmxPriority) {
        this.jmxPriority = jmxPriority;
    }

    public String getJmxType() {
        return jmxType;
    }

    public void setJmxType(String jmxType) {
        this.jmxType = jmxType;
    }

    public String getJmxDeliveryMode() {
        return jmxDeliveryMode;
    }

    public void setJmxDeliveryMode(String jmxDeliveryMode) {
        this.jmxDeliveryMode = jmxDeliveryMode;
    }

    public String getJmxReplyTo() {
        return jmxReplyTo;
    }

    public void setJmxReplyTo(String jmxReplyTo) {
        this.jmxReplyTo = jmxReplyTo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JMXHeaders{" +
                "jmxType='" + jmxType + '\'' +
                ", jmxExpires='" + jmxExpires + '\'' +
                ", jmxDeliveryMode='" + jmxDeliveryMode + '\'' +
                ", jmxReplyTo='" + jmxReplyTo + '\'' +
                ", jmxMessageId='" + jmxMessageId + '\'' +
                ", jmxTimestamp='" + jmxTimestamp + '\'' +
                ", jmxCorrelationId='" + jmxCorrelationId + '\'' +
                ", jmxPriority='" + jmxPriority + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```

And here is the JMX library method for sending a message:

```
String sendMessage(@Parameter(name = "headers",desc = "The headers to add to the message") Map<String, String> var1, @Parameter(name = "type",desc = "A type for the message") int var2, @Parameter(name = "body",desc = "The body (byte[]) of the message encoded as a string using Base64") String var3, @Parameter(name = "durable",desc = "Whether the message is durable") boolean var4, @Parameter(name = "user",desc = "The user to authenticate with") String var5, @Parameter(name = "password",desc = "The users password to authenticate with") String var6) throws Exception;
```

So I don’t understand how to send a message with a byte type and a message lifetime of 300 seconds, if there is no field for sending headers

Comment: By JMS, I know how to send, just the delivery itself is sent via the JMX protocol

Comment: I use JMX, since the whole system is built on it and I would like to send messages through JMX too

Comment: What is this "system" and why is "the whole" thing built on JMX? Why not simply use a messaging protocol to send messages? It would be much simpler.

Comment: It would be convenient, I do not argue. it's just that the requirements are just such that sending should be via jmx

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it is required that messages be sent via JMX vs. an actual messaging protocol?

Comment: There the solution was such that both the proofreading and the sending worked according to the JMX protocol

Comment: It's just that the requirements for the project are such that sending a message must be via the JMX protocol.

Comment: most likely it is possible to send unusual values ​​via JMX, such as type=354, not 3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

The expiration or "time-to-live" for a message cannot be set via a header or a property so it's not possible to do this via the `sendMessage` JMX operation.

If you want to send a "bytes" message (i.e. one where the body of the message is a `byte[]`) then you need to set the "type" to `4` and encode the `byte[]` of the body as a Base64 `String`.

To be clear, JMX is for *management* not for *messaging*. Therefore, you should really send messages using a messaging protocol, not JMX. Although there is a management method to send a message, it's very basic and not meant for anything but the most basic use-cases (e.g. basic tests to see if the broker is working).